# Как в contenteditable каждую часть текста занести в отдельный тэг?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Делаю свой текстовый редактор на div и contenteditable, и мне нужно чтобы каждая часть текста была в тэге span, как это сделать? Допустим как это выглядит сейчас:

```
<span>Всем привет это мой <b>текстовый</b> редактор!</span>
```

И как нужно мне:

```
<span>Всем привет это мой</span>  <span><b>текстовый</b> </span> <span>редактор!</span>
```

то есть обычный текст, и текст с другими тэгами  должны быть в отдельных тэгах span.

Comment: давай определимся для начала ,что есть часть текста, то есть ,есть какие то принципы отделения части текста от другой части? и зачем ты хочешь это сделать?

Comment: ну да, в отдельных тегах span должен быть обычный текст, а например, текст в теге b должен быть тоже в отдельном теге span, как это сделано у меня в примере